# How do I run 2 commands in a new command line window?

Tags: shell, command-line, gruntjs

I'd like to run jasmine tests through a grunt task. I do 
`jasmine` to run tests on the same window. `start jasmine` spawns a new window, runs the tests and leaves the window open.

I'd like the jasmine tests run on a new window, throw a `press any key to continue..` prompt in that new window and close that window on key-press.

So far, I tried `start jasmine & pause & exit` but the `pause` and `exit` commands simply apply to the parent window. I'd like them to act on the child window instead.

**Update**: `jasmine & pause & exit` does exactly what I need on my current window. I want this whole thing done on a new window. However a `start jasmine & pause & exit` starts jasmine on one window and `pause & exit` on my current window!

Answer (score 0):

You could easily wrap this in a batch file that has each of those steps laid out.

```
jasmine
pause
```

Then just call it with `start`.

Comment: I don't want to use a batch file. The commands are going to be part of a string inside `gruntfile.js`.

Comment: For CI servers I'll use plain `jasmine` command. This is for developers to have an easier time testing nodejs code